# Modify Ticket to Ride to For Six or More People - Thoughts?

Tags: house-rules, ticket-to-ride, board-game-adaptations

To get more than 5 people in on a game without having teams I was thinking about buying another set of train cars (or two or three), painting them a unique color, and then doing one of a few things...

1. Make every single path/line a double and make every double path/line
    a triple.
2. Make every single path/line a double and keep every double
    path/line a double.
3. Introduce a new mechanic that expands on suggestion 1 that involves
    paying an extra Locomotive (Wild) card.

New Mechanic

This might be a little too cutthroat, but if blocking people by claiming paths/lines are part of your strategy this could be fun.  If you want to claim/block a single path/line (which would now be doubles) you have to pay one extra Locomotive (Wild) for paths/lines that are 1-3 spots and two extra Locomotives for paths/lines that are 4-6 spots. Double paths/lines (which would now be triples) cannot be claimed/blocked.

Claimed paths/lines can we shown by laying one of the train pieces on its side or other any other clever way.  Coins, pieces of scrap paper, etc.  If you want to get crazy you can buy a set of train cars just for this purpose, paint them Silver or Gold, and use them as the first or last piece on that path/line.

I would also change the rule to trigger the last round on either 1 or 0 pieces or the first person who literally can't put down any more pieces.  Something of that nature.

Comment: "Cutthroat" ?? No, but probably a brutal and pointless way to triple the length of the game. Of course, it isn't at all clear what you mean by "claim" in this context. Doesn't the rule book use "claim" as the thing you do when you *trade* cards in hand for trains on the map?

Answer (score 2):

With six players the map might become a little too cluttered quickly: rather than adding new rules that make the game fiddlier, I would rather reduce the number of coaches, probably between 35 and 40. Hence players would focus on completing fewer tickets too: consider scrapping the longest tickets, which could become difficult to complete.

On a side note, why don't you just get the Old West map? It's for six players and a fine map and rules.

Comment: Also, one might want to add mitigation for blocking (e.g. stations). After all, one would be playing with the same map as four players.

Answer (score 1):

With 6 or more I would split into 2 games of ticket to ride since with 5 players the down time is already pretty high to keep player interested in my opinion.  I do think it is possibly to balance the mechanics of the game but the down time between plays would make it a very slow game and not the best for that size of group.  Part of what makes a game interesting is the time between decisions and adding more player while increase it since you have nothing to do on there turns.